# Fast check If the remainder is 1

Tags: probability, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, divisibility

Is there any fast method to 'say' that $R = (A \mod B)$ is $1$ or $R > 1$ or $R \neq1$ or $R > k>1$ ( where $k$ is a small integer on $32$ bits) without to actually calculate the real value of  $R=(A \mod B)$ ? In my case $A$ and $B$ are large positive integer numbers, e.g $512$ bits length.

Also, the same thing for $R=A^{P}\mod B$ (modular exponentiation) where all $A,P,B \geq512$ bits. i.e they are large numbers.  Also, a particular interest for me would be in case when $A = 2$, e.g $R=2^{P-1}\mod P$.
I am not interested in the real value of $R$ just to know if this fits one of the stated conditions

- $R > 1$
- $R \neq1$
- $R> k$ , k arbitrarily chosen, small positive integer on 32 bits

A probabilistic method would also be a welcomed solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Use the binary exponentiation

Comment: I haven't read the question, so I put the $R!=1$ on Ragnar's edit because the OP might really mean so. If it is not the case, someone can edit it.

Comment: No.  Outside of a few very special cases, you're not going to be able to shortcut those computations.  And for there to be a probabilistic method, there would need to be a significantly easier computation that you could do multiple times, each time shedding some light on whether your result was true.  I'm having trouble concieving of operators that are much quicker than the ones you are asking about, much less ones that would give you any insigts into your current calculations.